# Is it possible to keep 2 sockets in one android application all the time?

Tags: android

There is a solution for an android application to hold two sockets, which, from my point of view, is a very bad solution. Because sockets strongly devour all the resources of the phone. Does anyone have arguments for and against this decision?

Comment: what makes you think sockets " devour all the resources"?

Comment: You should start telling us why you want two sockets. And not three or four.

Comment: Sockets on their own do not "devour all the resources" but modules using sockets might, socket is medium, what/who is using those sockets matter

Comment: I put it wrong. I meant that it eats up a lot of resources. At least because you need to keep several threads that will support the socket

Comment: `Socket` should run in own `Thread`, thats true, but all other are just for your use case and implementation way. Probably these threads are unefficiently written thus consuming resources, mabye by leaking some data (how do you recognizing "devouring resources" - you have some inspection tool, memory analyzer, Android profiler etc. or just "visually" app slows down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering question: yes, it's possible to keep multiple socket connections

and quoting from question:

> sockets strongly devour all the resources

Thats simply not true... Probaly your code isn't well written and need some optimisation, put some logs and check all your operations aren't called multiple/too much times and collections keeping items aren't growing infinitely. And last, but maybe most important: be aware of memory leaks, you may occur/introduce some. Use [LeakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/) for inspecting this